# Unable to get Jython working on Mac

Tags: python, macos, jython

Installed Jython from the installer.

Set the Path as follows `/Users/user/jython2.7.0/bin`.

When tried to run Jython, received the following error.

```
MacBook-Pro:~ user$ jython
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/jython2.7.0/bin/jython", line 444, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/user/jython2.7.0/bin/jython", line 431, in main
    os.execvp(command[0], command[1:])
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 346, in execvp
_execvpe(file, args)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 370, in _execvpe
   func(file, *argrest)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Tried uninstalling other packages installed through Homebrew. But nothing positive.

Jython runs with the command `java -jar jython.jar` from the installation directory.

Tried running on a clean Macbook, everything runs fine.

Comment: seems like its using the system python libraries. Not sure if that is expected

Comment: Have you set up any Python-related environment variables in bash that might override the default search path? If so, I think Jython will follow them the same way CPython does, and you could end up using the CPython stdlib in Jython leading to exactly this error. (If you don't know how to answer, maybe just type `env |grep -i python` and paste the result into your question.)

Comment: `env |grep -i python` does not produce any results. However, I was able to resolve this problem by pointing the JAVA_HOME to jdk8 rather than jdk9. Not sure why this step worked.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved the problem by pointing JAVA_HOME to jdk1.8.0_131 rather than jdk9.0.4. Not sure why this solution works.